# JSF: HTTP GET Parameter Array

Tags: jsf, parameters, get, el

I'd like to pass an array as a GET parameter, say:

http://localhost/index.jsf?myArray=1stValue&myArray=2ndValue&myArray=3rdValue

Then I want to loop over that array:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{param['myArray']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{p}" />       
</c:forEach>
```

I know this code won't work.
But how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `#{paramValues}` instead. It refers to [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).

```xml
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{paramValues['myArray']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{p}" />       
</c:forEach>
```

or

```xml
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{paramValues.myArray}">
    <h:outputText value="#{p}" />       
</c:forEach>
```